Hom functor - direct product and direct sum - counterexamples
It is known that
$$\text{Hom}_\mathcal{R}(\bigoplus_iM_i,N)\cong\prod_i\text{Hom}_\mathcal{R}(M_i,N)$$
where $M_i$ and $N$ are $\mathcal{R}$-modules.
I've been struggling to provide counterexamples showing that
$$\text{Hom}_\mathcal{R}(\prod_iM_i,N)\ncong\bigoplus_i\text{Hom}_\mathcal{R}(M_i,N)$$
and
$$\text{Hom}_\mathcal{R}(M,\bigoplus_iN_i)\ncong\prod_i\text{Hom}_\mathcal{R}(M,N_i)$$
(the index set is assumed to be infinite)
I tried taking $M_i$ and $N$ to be $\mathbb{Z}$ , but so far I've been unable to complete the details.
I beleive that $\bigoplus\text{Hom}_i(\mathbb{Z},\mathbb{Z})\cong\bigoplus_i\mathbb{Z}$, integer sequences that are eventually zero, while the left-hand side consists of convergent integer sequences. I'm not sure if the reasoning is correct. And I couldn't provide any counterexamples for the second one. I would appreciate if anyone can help me with this.

Welcome to MSE. In this forum you're expected to show some effort in order to get help. Edit your question to include your work on the problem to avoid your question to be downvoted and eventually closed.

The problem with finite sums and finite product in abelian categories is that they are the same. Try taking infinite families

Yes, the hypothesis is that the index set is infinite, otherwise direct sum and direct product are equal. I'm adding that to the question

Duplicate question. Please use site search.

Sorry, I thoroughly searched the question, for the first one I found the counterexample by taking $M_i=\mathbb{Z}/n$ and $N=\mathbb{Q}$, but I could not find any counterexample for the second one. Besides, I was hoping to see other counterexamples.

For the second counter-example : take $R=M=\mathbb{Z}$. Then$\textrm{Hom}(Z,N)$ has a group structure naturally isomorphic to $N$. Thus $\textrm{Hom}(\mathbb{Z},\bigoplus_{i \in I} N_i) \cong \bigoplus_{i\in I} N_i$, and $\prod_{i\in I}\textrm{Hom}(\mathbb{Z}, N_i) \cong \prod_{i \in I} N_i$, and rhe two are not isomorphic in general.

@MartinBrandenburg Please, provide the link. As far as I know, there's still no reference for $\omega$-compact objects on MSE (and one poorly written on MO).
